# Is a forced integer buffer overflow legitime?

Tags: c++, c, overflow

I want to implement a Handletype like in this [example](http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/adventures-in-data-oriented-design-part-3b-internal-references/).

(Long story short: the structure `Handle` holds an `index`-member to an array with elements. Its other member `count` validates if the `index` is up to date, corresponding to the datas `countArray`. `count` and `countArray` are with a fixed size of a type/bitfield( u32 : 20bits))

To avoid being restricted to the 20bits of the generation/counter size, the following came into my mind: Why not let the `unsigned char count/countArray` overflow on purpose?
I could also do the same with the modulo method `( counter = ++counter % 0xff )`, but that is another additional operation then..
So let the count grow upto `0xff` and overflow will set it again to `0` when `0xff + 1` happens.
Is this legitime?

Here is my pseudo implementation (C++):

```
struct Handle
{
        unsigned short index;
        unsigned char count;
};

struct myData
{
        unsigned short curIndex;
        int* dataArray;
        unsigned char* countArray;

        Handle create()
        {
            // check if index not already used
            // create object at dataArray[handle.index]
            Handle handle;
            handle.index = curIndex;
            handle.count = countArray[curIndex]; 
            return handle;
        }

        void destroy( const Handle& handle )
        {
            // delete object at dataArray[handle.index]
            countArray[handle.index]++; // <-- overflow here?
        }

        bool isValid( const Handle& handle ) const
        {
            return handle.count == countArray[handle.index];
        }
};
```

EDIT #1: Yes, these integral types should all be unsigned (as indexes are)

Comment: Actually it shouldn't matter what integer type countArray is, as signed and unsigned integers will 'overflow' and be hold a different value then?!
I haven't seen this in any code yet, is this considered as a bad/poor way of coding?

Comment: In theory, incrementing a signed integer that has the value of "max integer" is _undefined behavior_.  This could include holding the same value.  In practice, I've never come across a signed variable than did not increment from max integer to min integer.  [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)

Comment: Just a side note for readers: What can happen here when overflowing, is that you accidently overwrite an existing handle. This is also explained in link of the first example: "This means that the generation overflows after 1048576 vertex buffers have been deleted in the same slot in our pool. Theoretically, this means that we could wrongly access a vertex buffer via an old handle that was generated more than 1048576 vertex buffer create/delete cycles ago, in that very slot. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not using `signed` types, you're safe.

Technically, `unsigned` types don't overflow:

#### 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]

> 46)This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a
> result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
> type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
> value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type.

Comment: If `signed char` was used for `countArray`, the result would be also be defined as there is a hidden integer promotion in `countArray[handle.index]++` expression.